# Best practice for checking for no index for an unsigned integer

Tags: c++, unsigned-integer

Say I have this function:

```
void doThings(uint8_t index) {
   if (an index is given) { ... }
}
```

Usually, an invalid index is -1, so that if statement would be `if (index != -1)`. What if I'm using an unsigned integer to represent the index? Would it be silly to change the function definition to a signed int, just so I can test for `-1`? Is there a universally accepted number representing 'no index' for unsigned ints?

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: [The standard library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/) uses `CLASSNAME::npos` with its value being the largest possible index, the maximum value `size_t` can represent (incidentally also `size_t(-1)`). If you want to follow that design choice, it might be a good idea to choose a wider type for the index.

Comment: Why `uint8_t`? Is there a requirement that this code not compile on systems that do not have an 8-bit integer type?

Comment: @PeteBecker Do you know a system that does not have a 8-bit integer type?

Comment: @Jens - yes. But that's irrelevant; there's no reason for deliberately making this code non-portable.

Comment: @PeteBecker Didn't want to criticize you, I asked just out of curiosity because I have never seen one. Also, portability may not be an issue, but in this case changing it would not create additional effort, so I agree with you.

Comment: @Jens - sorry for overreacting. But portability is **always** an issue. <g> Besides, far too many people use fixed-size integral types for no good reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *must* take into account the two situations in the same function, a better option may be to just provide a second parameter.

```
void doThings(uint8_t index, bool indexGiven) {
   if (indexGiven) { ... }
}
```

However, using two entirely different functions, one for when the index is given and one for when it is not, may lead to a cleaner design.

Comment: I think a better solution would be to create an index type which covers the semantics, e.g. either contains an index or a special invalid state.

Answer (score 3):

Simply overload `doThings`, something like this:

```
void doThings(uint8_t index) {
   // do things for a given index
}

void doThings() {
   // do things for no index
}
```

Or, if you're simply passing the results of a function, say `findElement` use a `std::pair` something like:

```
std::pair<std::uint8_t, bool> findElement(...);

void doThings(std::pair<std::uint8_t, bool>& arg) {
    if (arg.second) {
         // do things for given element arg.first
```

and call it with:

```
doThings(findElement(...));
```

Comment: That shifts the problem just one level up. As an example, if we have a function `std::uint8_t findElement(...)` and use the result to call `doThings`, we need to distinguish at the calling site between valid and invalid index and have the same problem. Also no index is something different than an invalid index.

Comment: Than have `findElement` return a `std::pair<std::uint8_t, bool>` to pass to `doThings` where the `bool` is `false` for no index.

Comment: I think optional<T> is a far better alternative in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It's not silly to change the function definition to use a signed integer so you can check against -1. This is a common practice.

However, if the function is part of a well-defined and documented API that is used by others, then you may not want to change the function to used a signed int. Instead, I would suggest using MAX_INT (or 0xFF for a uint8_t) as a flag for an invalid index.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a Maybe type.

```
// include some optional type, e.g. experimental/optional or boost/optional.hpp
using maybe_index = optional<std::uint8_t>;

void doThings(maybe_index index) {
   if (index) { ... }
   else { ... }
}
```

if I needed to be able to represent an index plus a special invalid state. GCC has an implementation of the proposed `std::optional` in `std::experimental`, and a Boost version is available.

Comment: Not from me. Using `optional<>` is the generalized way to extend any type with an additional value representing "none" or "no value". This is IMHO a must-have in every programmer's toolbox.

Comment: @downvoter Would anybody of the downvoters please add a comment why this is bad approach?

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself what values are valid for the index. Typically, you have an array and the length of the array defines the valid range. If that array happens to be 256 elements long, you use every possible value of a `uint8_t` as valid index, which means that you need more to represent an "invalid index". If the array is smaller, any index out of range of that array is invalid, customarily the highest value would be used for that (i.e. `static_cast<uint8_t>(-1)` or using functions from the `<limits>` header).

There are a bunch of approaches here already, like e.g. an additional flag, using `optional<uint8_t>` (which you should remember, as it is applicable in any place where you have similar requirements, not just for indices) or using an overload (which is probably not the way to go since this requires a compile-time decision).

Instead, I'd use a larger index type. The usual type used to represent an index is `size_t`, which is an unsigned integral type that typically has the size of a pointer (i.e. 32 or 64 bit on common computers). If you switch to that, you will be able to address even the largest of arrays that you will ever have in memory (not e.g. on disk!). With that, you can also use `static_cast<size_t>(-1)` as signal value to represent "invalid index".